# Flexbox Grouped Rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make the following arrangement of nested groups of inputs.

[image]

The closest I have managed to get is this snippet. However, in this snippet, the "fall" of the items to the next line is not properly grouped as demonstrated in the screenshot. Is there some pattern to use with flexbox to achieve this kind of grouping?

```css
div {
  margin: 3px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 60%;
}


.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 100% 1 1;
}

.group {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.item {
  flex: auto 1 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.group.d {
  flex-basis: 250px;
  flex-grow: 1000;
}

.group.s {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-grow: 300;
}

.group.e {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-grow: 300;
}

.group.x {
  flex-basis: 40px
}

.item input, .item button {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="group d">
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Mon</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Tue</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Wed</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Thu</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Fri</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Sat</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Sun</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group s">
            <div class = "item">
                <input value="Start Date">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input value="Start Time">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group e">
            <div class = "item">
                <input value="End Date">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input value="End Time">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group x">
            <div class = "item">
              <button>x</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you not considering to use media query to handle the `flex-basis` for each input group ?

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vxe19hk/) If you are considering to handle it from media query

Comment: It needs to adjust to the size of the container not the size of the screen as this is basically a component that can be loaded on pages, dialogues, popups, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to adjust the input groups to the size of the container and not the size of the screen.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 60%;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
}

.group {
    border: 2px solid green;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.item {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item input, .item button {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="group d">
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Mon</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Tue</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Wed</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Thu</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Fri</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Sat</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
              <button>Sun</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group s">
            <div class = "item">
                <input value="Start Date">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input value="Start Time">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group e">
            <div class = "item">
                <input value="End Date">
            </div>
            <div class = "item">
                <input value="End Time">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group x">
            <div class = "item">
              <button>x</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```